# Change network settings (net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl) in Dockerfile (or, ideally, for any container)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-network, docker-build

I want to change [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live#IP_packets) from 64 to 65 for every docker container (including those, which are started during `docker build` command).

My current approach is add command

```
RUN echo 65 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_default_ttl
```

to beginning of Dockerfile, but this gives me error

> mount: /proc/sys: permission denied

---

How can I change TTL, so that during `docker build` TTL 65 is used?

```
# Dockerfile

# command to change TTL
RUN ???
# this should executes as TTL is 65
RUN curl google.com
```

Comment: You're trying to change kernel settings from a container, that's not going to work. I would use `iptables` maybe on PREROUTING to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not recommended to change config directly from `/proc/sys`.

Try to change `iptables` instead:

```
 RUN iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -j TTL —ttl-set 65
```